# Django: template forloop multiple dictionaries

Tags: django, dictionary, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I need to load the the price of a liquor associated with the store, along wit the other data in the general liquor database. I know how to load the data in, and how to display in the info in two different tables, but I need that store price to simply be another row in the existing table, and I'm not sure how to do that. Here is the view:

```
def store(request, store_id=1):

    a = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id) 
    b = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID__exact=a).values_list('liquorID', flat=True)
    x = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID_exact=a)

    args = {}

    args['liquors'] = Liquor.objects.filter(id__in=b)
    args['prices'] = x
    args['a'] = a


    return render(request, 'store.html', args)
```

Here is the html:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        {% if liquors.count > 0 %}
            <table class="sortable"> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Liquor Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">Brand Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vendor Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for liquor in liquors %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ liquor.LiquorCode }}</td>
                            <td><a href="/stores/storeliquors/{{ a.StoreID }}/{{ liquor.id }}/">{{ liquor.BrandName }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ liquor.VendorName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ liquor.StorePrice }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% else %}
            <p>None to show!</p>
        {% endif %}
    </code>
</pre>
```

Models:

```
    class StoreLiquor(models.Model):
        StoreLiquorID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        liquorID = models.ForeignKey(Liquor)
        storeID = models.ForeignKey(Store)
        StorePrice = models.DecimalField('Store Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Liquor(models.Model):
        LiquorCode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Liquor Code', max_length=5)
        BrandName = models.CharField('Brand Name', max_length=32)
        ADANumber = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('ADA Number', max_length=3)
        ADAName = models.CharField('ADA Name', max_length=25)
        VendorName = models.CharField('Vendor Name', max_length=25)
        LiquorType = models.CharField('ADA Name', max_length=20)
        Proof = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
        BottleSize = models.CharField('Bottle Size', max_length=7)
        PackSize = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('PackSize', max_length=3)
        OnPremisePrice = models.DecimalField('On Premise Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        OffPremisePrice = models.DecimalField('Off Premise Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        ShelfPrice = models.DecimalField('Shelf Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        GlobalTradeItemNumber1 = models.BigIntegerField('Global Trade Item Number 1', max_length=14)
        GlobalTradeItemNumber2 = models.BigIntegerField('Global Trade Item Number 2', max_length=14)

    class Store(models.Model):
        StoreID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Can you add the model definitions?

Comment: @Wolph, I added them.

Comment: Missing the Store model

Comment: @ dan-klasson, I added it but I since nothing more than the ID field is being used here, I doubt you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

View:

```
def store(request, store_id=1):
    store = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id) 

    args = {}
    args['store'] = store

    return render(request, 'store.html', args)
```

Template:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        {% if store.storeliquor_set.count %}
        <table class="sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Liquor Code</th>
                    <th scope="col">Brand Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Vendor Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for storeliquor in store.storeliquor_set.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ storeliquor.liquorID.LiquorCode }}</td>
                    <td><a href="/stores/storeliquors/{{ a.StoreID_id }}/{{ liquor.liquorID_id }}/">{{ liquor.liquorID.BrandName }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ storeliquor.liquorID.VendorName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ storeliquor.StorePrice }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        {% else %}

        <p>None to show!</p>

        {% endif %}
    </code>
</pre>
```

Although I would recommend you to change your model to something like this (according to the python style guide):

```
class StoreLiquor(models.Model):
    liquor = models.ForeignKey(Liquor)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    price = models.DecimalField('Store Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Liquor(models.Model):
    liquor_code = models._positiveSmallIntegerField('Liquor Code', max_length =5)
    brand_name = models.CharField('Brand Name', max_length =32)
    ada_number = models._positiveSmallIntegerField('ADA Number', max_length =3)
    ada_name = models.CharField('ADA Name', max_length =25)
    vendor_name = models.CharField('Vendor Name', max_length =25)
    liquor_type = models.CharField('ADA Name', max_length =20)
    proof = models.DecimalField(max_digits =3, decimal_places =1)
    bottle_size = models.CharField('Bottle Size', max_length =7)
    pack_size = models._positiveSmallIntegerField('PackSize', max_length =3)
    on_premise_price = models.DecimalField('On Premise Price', max_digits =5, decimal_places =2)
    off_premise_price = models.DecimalField('Off Premise Price', max_digits =5, decimal_places =2)
    shelf_price = models.DecimalField('Shelf Price', max_digits =5, decimal_places =2)
    global_trade_item_number_1 = models.BigIntegerField('Global Trade Item Number 1', max_length =14)
    global_trade_item_number_2 = models.BigIntegerField('Global Trade Item Number 2', max_length =14)

class Store(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: there are actually other things defined in the store model, like an address and a foreign key to users. but anyways, I'm getting an error on the template on this line. '{% for storeliquor in store.storeliquor_set %}' I'm getting a type error, ''RelatedManager' object is not iterable'

Comment: My bad... should have a `.all` at the end.

Comment: Actually I fixed it you have to add a .all. '{% for storeliquor in store.storeliquor_set.all %}